# playframework 1.2.4 how to use jar with JPA entities already existing

Tags: playframework

I have a jar with JPA entities in it from another application with the persistence.xml file.  Is there a way to tweak play so

1. It fills in the persistence.xml with property values
2. It sets up the in-memory database still and allows us to save/query, etc.

Currently, I get an error "A JPA error occurred (The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.)"

ps. I have my entity jar in the lib directory of course with the persistence.xml file there AND it works until I pull all my entities out of my model(if no entities in model, it doesn't seem to work).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presently in a similar situation, but using Play 2.0.1, so I'm not sure I could answer your two questions, but I do believe that I could potentially help with the error you receive.

My persistence.xml file set-up for Hibernate and the in-memory database:

```
    <persistence-unit name="testUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jar-file>path/to/jar-file.jar/jar-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:events"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

What I imagine is you do not include your jar-file, so although you have the jar in your build path, it is not recognized by your JPA Entity Manager.

Also, you should check to make sure you do not need to place your persistence.xml file in your /conf/META-INF folder, though this may be Play 2.0.1 specific, but it was something else that I encountered working on mine.